# Location of Database?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

For my current project I would like to test out the application on a different computer and put my database on a server.

In other projects I looked at my `connectionstring` to find where the database is located but this time it doesn't tell me where it is located.

```
    <add name="Backend.Properties.Settings.autobusConnectionString"
        connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=autobus;Integrated Security=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I created my database with `SQL Server 2008 R2` and implemented it with LINQ-TO-SQL using `Linq-To-SQL Classes`.

So my question is, where is it located on my computer and how would I change the location of the database?
Thanks for the help,
Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Data Source=.` is the servername. `.` is localhost. Change to `Data Source=YourServer` or `Data Source=YourServer\YourInstance`.

Comment: Thanks, but where is the database located on my computer? I can't find it's location.

Comment: Open management studio, connect to `.`, create a backup of your database and restore that to your other server.

Answer (score 2):

The datasource is set to '.', which is shorthand for localhost. (i.e. your computer).

The server name is likely to be the same as your computers Hostname.

Comment: Thanks, but where is the database located on my computer? I can't find it's location.

Comment: That depends entirely on how you configured your instance in the first place. It is likely in C:/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server somewhere.

Comment: If you have Management Studio installed you can use that to find out